# BITS credential problem

Tags: download, credentials, microsoft-bits, bits-service

I have a service to download file using credential domain\user but get this error :
ErrorCode [-2147023582] 80070522 
Description [A required privilege is not held by the client.] 
ErrorContext [RemoteFileError] 
at Windows Server 2003 64 bits
I'm setting credential so :

```
                bc.AuthenticationScheme = AuthenticationScheme.Negotiate;
                bc.AuthenticationTarget = AuthenticationTarget.Server;
```

The user has full access rights on source and destination folders.
Using SharpBits library.
It seems to be missing some right of access yet. Any suggestions?

[EDIT]
It seems that there is some failure in resource access provided by the BITS service.
Still investigating.

[EDIT]
Investigating the rights to use BITS.
-with the command "sc sdshow bits" I get this output on the environment where it works :

```
D:(A;;CCLCSWRPWPDTLOCRRC;;;SY)
(A;;CCDCLCSWRPWPDTLOCRSDRCWDWO;;;BA)
(A;;CCLCSWLOCRRC;;;AU)(A;;CCLCSWRPWPDTLOCRRC;;;PU)
S:(AU;FA;CCDCLCSWRPWPDTLOCRSDRCWDWO;;;WD)
```

-where the copy does not work :

```
D:(A;;CCLCSWRPWPDTLOCRRC;;;SY)
(A;;CCDCLCSWRPWPDTLOCRSDRCWDWO;;;BA)
(A;;CCLCSWLOCRRC;;;IU)(A;;CCLCSWLOCRRC;;;SU)
(A;;CR;;;AU)
(A;;CCLCSWRPWPDTLOCRRC;;;PU)
S:(AU;FA;CCDCLCSWRPWPDTLOCRSDRCWDWO;;;WD)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution : added the user "NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK" permissions to read at folders in all remote hosts.
That's it.